# Apply custom function on each frame of a video with variable framerate

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to apply a custom python function on every frame of a video, and create the video with modified frames as output. My input video is a mkv file, with variable framerate, and I'd like to get the same thing as output, so one frame in the input matches one in the output at the exact same time.

I tried to use [this example](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples#tensorflow-streaming) of ffmpeg-python. However, it seems that the timestamp info are lost in the pipes. The output video has 689 frames when the input only has 300 (the durations also aren't a match, with 27s vs 11s for the input).

I also tried to first process each frame in my video and save the transformed version as PNGs. Then I "masked" the input video with the processed frames. This seems to be better because the output video has the same 11s duration than the input, but the frame count doesn't match (313 vs 300).

Code for the python-ffmpeg solution:

```py
width = 1920
height = 1080
process1 = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(in_filename)
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)

process2 = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
    .output(out_filename, pix_fmt='yuv420p')
    .overwrite_output()
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
)

while True:
    in_bytes = process1.stdout.read(width * height * 3)
    if not in_bytes:
        break
    in_frame = (
        np
        .frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8)
        .reshape([height, width, 3])
    )

    # Just add 1 to the pixels for the example
    out_frame = in_frame + 1

    process2.stdin.write(
        out_frame
        .astype(np.uint8)
        .tobytes()
    )

process2.stdin.close()
process1.wait()
process2.wait()
```

Code for the overlay solution:

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -i test/%d.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=0:0" -copyts out.mkv
```

Is there any other solution I didn't think about to perform what I'm trying to do? It doesn't seem to be **that** complicated but I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

Here are the logs for the input and output pipes of the python-ffmpeg solution.

Input

```sh
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'in.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf59.17.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 45702 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive), yuvj420p(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.134.100 h264_nvenc
      DURATION        : 00:00:11.483000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.17.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2985984 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:11.483000000
      encoder         : Lavc59.20.100 rawvideo
frame=  689 fps=154 q=-0.0 Lsize= 4185675kB time=00:00:11.48 bitrate=2985984.1kbits/s dup=389 drop=0 speed=2.57x
```

Output

```sh
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1244160 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 1920x1080, 1244160 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[libx264 @ 0000025afaf11140] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0000025afaf11140] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000025afaf11140] 264 - core 164 r3081 19856cc - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'images/videos/out.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.17.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 fps, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.20.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=  689 fps= 11 q=-0.0 Lsize= 4185675kB time=00:00:11.48 bitrate=2985984.1kbits/s dup=389 drop=0 speed=0.181x    
video:4185675kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

Comment: Can you post the ffmpeg log of your decoding process? I venture to say that your `rawvideo` output is no longer variable rate

Comment: @kesh just added them in the question

Comment: Sorry, I meant to the log of the first ffmpeg call.

Comment: @kesh just added the logs of the first call. Indeed we can see that there are 689 frames exported to the pipe. I tried to set the vsync option for the input. It works: only 300 frames are sent with it, but unfortunately, the the new video is 12s instead of 11 so the timestamps are still not sent correctly.

Comment: yeah, my understanding is (although I don't have any 1st person experience with VFR data) that FFmpeg doesn't work all that well with variable frame rate. You might want to look into reading directly from matroska video (someone has posted python code on github). I'll be on a look out and if I see a solution, I'll let you know. (Or someone else can chime in with a solution).

Comment: Just learned something related to this. Set `-vsync 0` option, which passes through its timestamp from the demuxer to the muxer. You will still have a problem though... You don't have access to the timestamps to create a VFR output. You likely need to use an external to extract the timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, as I've been able to solve the issue with the help of kesh in the comments.

There are basically two things:

- `vsync passthrough` is required for the input video, to keep the number of frames
- another external tool ([MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/index.html)) has to be used twice to extract timestamps from the initial video and apply them to the output

Below is the relevant code to perform the whole operation using python and subprocess. You can use the following line on both input and output video to check that the timestamps are indeed the same for each frame: `ffprobe -show_entries packet=pts_time,duration_time,stream_index video.mkv`

```py
    width = 1920
    height = 1080

    process1 = (
        ffmpeg
        .input('in.mkv', vsync='passthrough')
        .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
        .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
    )

    process2 = (
        ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
        .output('temp.mkv', pix_fmt='yuv420p')
        .overwrite_output()
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
    )

    while True:
        in_bytes = process1.stdout.read(width * height * 3)
        if not in_bytes:
            break
        in_frame = (
            np
            .frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8)
            .reshape([height, width, 3])
        )
        # Keep thing simple, just add 1 to each pixel    
        out_frame = in_frame + 1

        process2.stdin.write(
            out_np
            .astype(np.uint8)
            .tobytes()
        )

    process2.stdin.close()
    process1.wait()
    process2.wait()

    # Extract timestamps from input video
    subprocess.run(['mkvextract', 'in.mkv', 'timestamps_v2', '0:timestamps.txt'])
    # Apply extracted timestamps to create synchronized output video
    subprocess.run(['mkvmerge', '-o', 'out.mkv', '--timestamps', '0:timestamps.txt', 'temp.mkv'])

    # Clean up
    os.remove('temp.mkv')
    os.remove('timestamps.txt')
```